# How does vis-network get the real-time position of the center of the node and the top left corner under any circumstances?

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network, visnetwork

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rochappy/hnp5gzjt/)

```
.wrap{
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#mynetwork {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.origin {
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;

  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="mynetwork"></div>
  <div class="origin"></div>
</div>
```

```
        // create an array with nodes
    var nodes = [{
            id: 1,
      "shape": "dot",
            label: 'node1',
      x: 5,
      y: 5
         }, {
            id: 2,
      "shape": "dot",
            label: 'node2',
      x: 50,
      y: 75
         }];

    // create an array with edges
    var edges = [
        {from: 1, to: 2},
        {from: 1, to: 3}
    ];

    // create a network
    var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
    var data = {
        nodes: nodes,
        edges: edges
    };
    var options = {
        interaction: {
        hover: true,
      },
      physics: {
        enabled: false
      }
    };
    var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);    
    network.on("hoverNode", function (t) {
        var nodeID = t.node;
      // I want to get the real-time position of the center of the node and the upper left corner under any circumstances (zoom in, zoom out, move)
        // ... ?
    });
```

I hope that the coordinates of the node and the upper left corner can be obtained in real time. In any case, for example, the position of 'node1' is obtained when zooming in. After the node is moved, it is a new position. It should be changed. The distance from the red dot should be calculated.

Answer (score 1):

```
    const node = network.getPositions([nodeID])[nodeID]
    const corner = visGraph.canvasToDOM({
      x: node.x,
      y: node.y
    })
```

reference [GitHub vis-networkissues/128](https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/issues/128)